# Преобразования для примитивов

Tags: javascript

Почему так получается? Разве не должно быть одно и то же?

```
"$" + 4 + 5 = "$45"
4 + 5 + "$"= "9$"
```

Comment: в первой строке - первый элемент выражения - это строка, соответственно все остальные `+` - это конкатенация строки. Во второй строке - первый оператор `+` - выполняет сложение, а потом, при конкатенации со строкой "$" происходит преобразование полученной суммы к строке

Answer (score 0):

Интерпретатор все команды выполняет последовательно, поэтому ваш код можно разложить вот так:

```
("$" + 4) + 5 => "$4" + 5 => "$45"
```

Во втором же случае, сначала арифметическая операция, а потом конкатенация

```
(4 + 5) + "$" => 9 + "$" => "9$"
```